# get combinations of strings line by line

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have 5 vertical strings which were generated in order of probability by my classifier.  If the classifiers confidence was very high I want to keep that classification but for the low ones I would like to vary between all possible combinations.

so my data looks like this:

```
aa aa aa aa aa
ab ac aa ad ae
aa ab af ae ag
```

and I would like to get all of the possible combinations

```
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa ...
ab ac aa ad ae ae ab ac aa ad ...
aa ab af ae ag aa ab af ae ag...
```

I tried itertools but I can't seem to find the right tool to do this. Does anyone know how to do this?

[UPDATE]

This is what I have tried so far:

```
for x in new_lines:
    for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j in permutations(x.split(), 10):
        print '{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(a.rstrip('\n'), b.rstrip('\n'), c.rstrip('\n'), d.rstrip('\n'), e.rstrip('\n'), f.rstrip('\n'), g.rstrip('\n'), h.rstrip('\n'), i.rstrip('\n'), j.rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: It looks like you want the [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=permutations#itertools.permutations) function.

Comment: @MikeRobins, yes that is what I have been trying with itertools. I put 10 so it wouldn't explode but the output is empty.  If I do 5 it works

Comment: there are no 10 element permutations of a 5 element set, so empty output sounds correct.  Also I suggest if you find yourself typing out code that is so repetitive use loops and lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want triplet combinations with replacement of the string `"aa ab ac ad ae af ag"`, excluding entries where all elements are equal.

**Code**

```
import itertools as it


iterable = "aa ab ac ad ae af ag".split()

combs = it.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, 3)
pred = lambda x: len(set(x)) != 1
results = list(filter(pred, combs))
transposed = list(zip(*results))
```

**Demo**

```
>>> for line in transposed:
...     print(line)
('aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', ...)
('aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', ...)
('ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', ...)
```

**Options**

You can simplify this code as a generator in one line:

```
transposed = zip(*(i for i in it.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, 3) if len(set(i)) != 1))
```